# Displaying SQL Server table data in webform

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I have an application which is supposed to allow a user to view pets from a table in the database.

Picture of web form design and Pets data table:
[image: Picture of web form design and Pets data table]

Here is my code for the button:

```
protected void viewAnimalsBreedButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\FrendsWithPaws.mdf;Integrated Security=True");

        cnn.Open();
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT PetID, Breed, Name, Age, Gender, Picture, Sanctuary FROM Pets WHERE Breed='+ breedDropDownList.SelectedValue +'", cnn);
        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        petsGridView.DataSource = reader;
        petsGridView.DataBind();
        cnn.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write("error" + ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

To start with I have a `dropdownlist` for the pets breed, when I select a `breed` in the `dropdown` and click view animals, I would like the `gridview` to show me the pets (with most of the contained information) with this breed... I would then like this to work for `Species` and `Sanctuary`...

Currently when I select a breed and click view animals nothing happens, as shown in the picture below:

Picture of web form after selection of 'House' breed and click of view animals button:
[image: Picture of web form after selection of 'House' breed and click of view animals button]

How do I get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly you should always use [parameterized queries](https://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/) to avoid [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) and getting rids of this kind of issues.
And secondly, you need to create a `DataTable` and fill it though data reader and bind your table to grid:

```
cnn.Open();
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT PetID, Breed, Name, Age, Gender, Picture, " +
                                    "Sanctuary FROM Pets where Breed = @Breed ", cnn);

command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Breed", breedDropDownList.SelectedValue);

DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Load(command.ExecuteReader());    
petsGridView.DataSource = table;
petsGridView.DataBind();
cnn.Close();
```

Although specify the type directly and use the Value property is more better than `AddWithValue`. https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Comment: Great, the updated code you put has worked, thanks alot! i didnt know you could use the @Breed paramater.addwithvalue

Answer (score 0):

You have to load read data to `datatable` first:

```
protected void viewAnimalsBreedButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\FrendsWithPaws.mdf;Integrated Security=True");

        cnn.Open();
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT PetID, Breed, Name, Age, Gender, Picture, Sanctuary FROM Pets WHERE Breed='" +  breedDropDownList.SelectedValue + "'", cnn);
        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        var dataTable = new DataTable();
        dataTable.Load(dataReader);
        petsGridView.DataSource = dataTable;
        petsGridView.DataBind();
        cnn.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write("error" + ex.ToString());
    }
}
```